# How to switch pin direction in PIO

Tags: pi-pico

I want to implement the Gameboy Advance "Multi-Play/Multiboot" protocol in PIO.

Essentially the way this protocol works is as follows:

> 4 pins: SI, SO, SD, SC
>
> - master knows it's master because SI=low (hardwired in the plug)
> - master starts its clocking thing on SC
> - master sends start(high)+16bit+stop(low) via SD
> - everyone reads that
> - master sets SO=low
> - slave1 sees SI=low (SI on each slave plug is wired to SO on the previous plug)
> - slave1 sends start+16bit+stop
> - everyone reads that
> - slave1 sets SO=low ... (repeat last 4 steps for slave 2 and 3)
> - master stops its clocking thing, sets SC=high
> - everyone sets SO=high

see also [GBATEK](https://problemkaputt.de/gbatek.htm#siomultiplayermode).

So what I'd need to implement, in pseudocode, is as far as I can tell:

```
  is_master = SI
  sent_bits = 0
  total_bits = 0
  loop:
    if(is_master):
      SC=1; // probably some sideset magic
    if(SI==0 && sent_bits <= 18):
      SD_dir=output;
      if(!is_master)
        wait_for(SC==1);
      if(sent_bits==0):
        somehow_tell_pico_program(total_bits); // so we know which participant we are
        SD=1;
      elseif(sent_bits==17):
        SD=0;
      elseif(sent_bits==18):
        SO=0;
      else:
        SD=tx_fifo;
      sent_bits++;
    else:
      if(is_master):
        SC=0; // probably some sideset magic
      SD_dir=input;
      if(!is_master):
        wait_for(SC==0)
      rx_fifo=SD;
    if(is_master):
    total_bits++;
      if(total_bits==72)
        SC=1;
        SO=1;
        break;
    wait_for(tx_fifo);
```

Now, I'm really new to PIO programming, and have no idea how to do something like switching pin directions midway, and telling the pico the number of bits when SI went low (so it knows whether it's master or which of the slaves).

Note the bus is (due to how I hook up the pico to the port, via "2 resistors + 1 fet" levelshifters) open-drain, in case that's helpful somehow.

Comment: That looks likely to be too large for a PIO program.  A PIO program can have a maximum of 32 instructions (unless you  use a highly advanced technique).

Comment: @joan good point, do you have an idea how to fix that? maybe write multiple PIO programs for things like "i'm the master and want to send the first packet" followed by "i'm the master and want to listen for the slaves", and "i'm a slave and want to listen" followed "i'm a slave and want to send" (followed by listening again) and somehow switch them out real fast? can I even switch them out that fast? we're talking up to 115200bps here. alternatively given i don't need PIO for anything else, could i "preload" multiple state machines, map them to the same pins and turn them on/off?

Comment: I would just write a normal C program.  Is the Pico to be master or slave?

Comment: that's the thing, it's gonna be both. if it was always the master that'd be easy, but if it's clocked externally i don't wanna deal with any inaccuracies from e.g. interrupts (it's gonna do USB i/o while that's happening, which afaik does have its own timing weirdness requiring regular interrupts). I actually tried writing this in C on a stm32f103 "blue pill" before, and that was one thing that really got in the way there in slave mode

Comment: I suggest you ask the question on https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=143 I think it is too broad for this site and I know there is a lot of PIO/Pico expertise at that forum.

Comment: thanks, will try :) i'll also just try doing like you said and implement the protocol in C, then maybe see if i can outsource any tight loops (like the actual sending/receiving of a 16bit packet) to the PIO as required.